# How to get child component of an active tab of a tabpanel in extjs4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a simple tabpanel. I want to fetch currently active tab's child components and destroy them and `doLayout()`. The following code won't work:

```
Ext.getCmp('centertabpanel').getActiveTab().items.destroy();
```

Comment: @ryan i get no errors and nothing happns.probably my qs is how to get all child elements of a component and destroy them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind here is that tabs in TabPanel's in ExtJS just need to be a [BoxComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.BoxComponent) in ExtJS 3 or a [Component](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Component) in ExtJS 4. This means that tabs are not required to hold children elements. However, if you know that your `centertabpanel` has tabs with [Containers](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Container), then you have two options:

If your tab is a container that has `autoDestroy` set to true (that is the default), then just use:

```
    Ext.getCmp('centertabpanel').getActiveTab().removeAll();
```

If you want to set `autoDestroy` to false, then use the following code:

```
    Ext.getCmp('centertabpanel').getActiveTab().each(function(item, idx, len) {
        item.destroy();
    });
```

`.each()` is defined on [MixedCollection](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection). It will execute the function in the first parameter against all of the child items, in order. As a side note, if you return false inside the function, then it will stop all iteration of elements.